# facebook api server error 500 issue

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to use facebook api let my website to login with facebook.
It was working properly however it has error message.
I check the error log,it's show

[Thu May 31 17:10:53 2012] [error] [client 114.34.249.224] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:2110:3f01:face:b00c:0:1: No route to host\n  thrown in /home/fb3/src/base_facebook.php on line 886

How can I fix the problem?

thanks.

## Update:

my routing table didn't include also inet6:

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire

default            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     UGS        57  1209297   bge0

127.0.0.1          link#2             UH          0       17    lo0

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24    link#1             U           0    24067   bge0

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      link#1             UHS         0      192    lo0

Internet6:

Destination                       Gateway                       Flags      Netif Expire

::1                               ::1                           UH          lo0

fe80::%lo0/64                     link#2                        U           lo0

fe80::1%lo0                       link#2                        UHS         lo0

ff01:2::/32                       fe80::1%lo0                   U           lo0

ff02::%lo0/32                     fe80::1%lo0                   U

and my inet4 settings:
$ more rc.conf

-- sysinstall generated deltas -- # Tue Jul 13 18:02:58 2010
 Created: Tue Jul 13 18:02:58 2010
 Enable network daemons for user convenience.
 Please make all changes to this file, not to /etc/defaults/rc.conf.
 This file now contains just the overrides from /etc/defaults/rc.conf.

keymap="us.iso"

defaultrouter="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

hostname="domain.com"

ifconfig_bge0="inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0"

sshd_enable="YES"

apache22_enable="YES"

mysql_enable="YES"

sendmail_enable="NONE"

proftpd_enable="YES"

named_enable="YES"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying an IPv6 address to get through to Facebook, and something along the way is not set up correctly for IPv6.

As a quick, manual hack, find references to graph.facebook.com in the script and quickly hard code as the IPv4 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) address for graph.facebook.com. If this works, then change the script back and either:

1. Make your server run IPv4 only (easiest, but not forward looking)
2. Check what hardware between you and the server is not IPv6 configured, and get it changed (a lot harder than it dsounds - probably means new routers somewhere, youch, but if you don't do this, no point have IPv6 on the server!).

Comment: My server is run IPV4 only, I'm sure. Maybe the ISP problem? and I try to edit base_facebook.php, and change the code to IPv4 IP,it's work. but still cant use the fb login function. I'm confuse now...

Comment: You're server is (was) running IPv6 - that's clear from your error message. Now you'll have a different problem and we'll need new information to help get you over that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux, you probably have the IPv6 kernel module loaded and since it's loaded, when you make a DNS request, it will return to you first an IPv4 address then followed by an IPv6 address.  If for some reason you fail to connect to IPv4, then your system will try the next address and since it is IPv6 and you do not have IPv6 connectivity, you will get the above error.

Comment: I'm running freebsd 8.0, but I did't set up any config about v6.